# Error while using ConfigParser in Python code

Tags: python

In my python code, I use a lot of urls. So, I need to store all the urls in another file and use them whenever I need. I’m trying to use ConfigParser. For example,

I store urls in the following file named path.cfg :

```
[URLs]

path1 = "http://gstore.unm.edu/apps/epscor/search/collections.json?version=3&theme=Climate"

path2 = "http://gstore.unm.edu/apps/epscor/search/collection/%s/datasets.json?version=3"
```

Next is my program code,

```
import ConfigParser
import requests
import webbrowser

filepath = 'path.cfg'

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(filepath)
value = config.items('URLs')

url1 = value[0][1] # i.e., path1
r = requests.get(url1)
```

Could anyone please tell me what’s the mistake on the last line of code?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the error you get.

Comment: Have you actually *checked* that `url1` is what you expect?

Comment: Can _you_ tell _us_ the mistake on the last line of code?  i.e. What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your url's start and end with double quotes: `"`, which causes problems with `requests.get()`.

**Solution**: remove the `"` from path.cfg

```
[URLs]

path1 = http://gstore.unm.edu/apps/epscor/search/collections.json?version=3&theme=Climate

path2 = http://gstore.unm.edu/apps/epscor/search/collection/%s/datasets.json?version=3
```